# Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Toolkit - Map legend with more than 2 levels

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I'm having trouble creating a multi-level legend for my map. I have a `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` that has 3 visible layers beneath it. The first layer then has 7 sub-layers beneath it. In my legend I want to show the following (I'll user my layers' actual names):

```
Contaminated Soil
-----> Former Cleanup Areas
       -----> Soil Remediation Complete
```

For the last layer `Soil Remediation Complete` I want to actually display the color coding associated with the layer.

This is what my code is so far:

```xml
<esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView">
    <esri:Map x:Name="Map1" >
        <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="Base Layer" DisplayName="Base Layer" ServiceUri=https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer  />    
        <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="Contaminated Areas" DisplayName="Contaminated Areas"  ServiceUri="https://xxxxxxxx" />    
    </esri:Map>    
</esri:MapView>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to creating a legend for this. I have been surfing the web for 2 days now looking for something that can help but am coming up empty.

Comment: I think you are more likely to attract potential answerers if you specify in your question body and tags which API from the ArcGIS platform you are using.